# function does not get rest of string if a capital letter is found

Tags: c

I have a function called `preprocess` that reads each word in each line from a text file and then converts the characters to lowercase if an uppercase letter is found.

```
/*
 preprocessor, convert string to lowercase
 and trim the punctuations (. , ? !) at the back
*/
char* preprocess(char* string){
    #if DEBUG
        printf("\nbefore preprocess, string: %s \n", string);
    #endif
    
    int i=0;

    while(string[i] != '\0') { // convert to lower case
        if (string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] < 'Z') {
            string[i] += 32;
            i++;
        }        
    
    
        while(true) {
            i--;
            if(i < 0) {
                #if DEBUG
                    printf("punctuation found \n");
                #endif

                printf("\n");
                return string;
                
            } else if((string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z') || (string[i] >= '0' && string[i] <= '9')){
                string[i + 1]='\0';
                break;
            }
        }

        i=0;

        while(true) {
            if ((string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z') || (string[i] >= '0' && string[i] <= '9')){
                break;
            } else {
                string = &string[i + 1];
            }

            i++;
        }
    
        #if DEBUG
            printf("after preprocess, string: %s\n", string);
        #endif
    } 
    
    return string;
}
```

Right now, the function does attempt to convert an uppercase string to lowercase but it only outputs the first character and not the rest of the string as seen below:

```
Output:
before preprocess, string: address. 
punctuation found 


before preprocess, string: Please 
after preprocess, string: p
punctuation found
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong in the function?

Comment: Hint (Though it won't fix your problem): `isupper()` and `toupper()` are standard functions...

Comment: Maybe you want 3 separate loop, and not one containing the other 2? There are other logic errors, like the the 3rd loop where you are trying to find the end of the string. And why do you try to do that when you already know the end of the string after stripping trailing punctuations? And when stripping punktuations, what happens when the string doesn't contain any characters in the range `'a'`...`'z'`?

Comment: Rather than `string[i] < 'Z'`, I'd expect `string[i] <= 'Z'`

Comment: `i` is used in different overlapping contexts; I don't think you want this?

Answer (score 0):

`string[i + 1]='\0'` so whenever you find an uppercase (like `P`) you change it to lowercase, increment i, then later you decrement i (go back to `p`) and you add a '\0' right after, which makes you exit the first loop. This is not what you want to do I guess.